# Ubuntu stuck on purple ubuntu loading screen after resizing partition

Tags: boot

I expanded my Ubuntu partition using Grub on the Live CD installation.

It has however refused to get past the loading screen since I did this

Comment: If you resized `/` partition, you have to re-install grub now.

Comment: Can you get to a tty screen using Ctrl + Alt + F3,4,5,..?

Comment: @user9178045 Is the screen solid purple, or is there an Ubuntu logo with 1-5 dots under the logo?  Please click [edit] and answer the question above as well as mine; please don't use Add Comment, but instead put your results into your question with [edit].